# In time or on time

Tags: prepositions, word-usage

I must hurry to get home ___ to watch the match.
The blank should be filled with 'in time' or 'on time'?

Comment: It's "in time" or "on time", depending on the context. For example, "He was in time for the meeting" could also mean ahead of time, early, not late, etc. Usually "on time" means punctual, exactly, etc.

Answer (score 2):

It should be *in time*. *on time* is usually used without a qualifier, the reason for the deadline is either stated previously or known a priori. Examples:

> He got home in time for dinner.
>   Dinner was served on time.

This [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=in%20time%20to%2Con%20time%20to&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cin%20time%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Con%20time%20to%3B%2Cc0) shows that *on time to* is not used much compared to *in time to*.

Comment: He was *in time* to catch the train. The train was *on time*. He was *in time* for the start of the match. The match started *on time*.